# prevent css inheritance on child element

Tags: css, inheritance, iframe

Building my CMS I am using CKeditor to edit the content of a TEXTAREA.

When loading a page in the CMS, the content is shown in a DIV (preview). After clicking 'edit' in the CMS toolbar  the content is loaded in a IFRAME for CKEditor so it can be edited.

Both DIV (preview) and CKeditor are using the same CSS for the content.

The content in the DIV is offcourse effected by the CSS from the CMS itself and I like to prevent that behavior.

The only way I know of is to use an iframe instead of a DIV.

I can get this to work but I am curious if there are other practices.

Answer (score 0):

There’s no way of taking an element out of the cascade without (as you say) using an `<iframe>` or other page inclusion methods (`<frameset>` and `<object>` spring to mind).

You could, of course, write your CSS with a bunch of overrides for your preview, but that’s complicated and fragile.

I’d suggest just going down the `<iframe>` route: it has the least chance of going wrong.

Comment: Fragile? What's wrong with giving the `div` the same explicit CSS as you would the contents of the `iframe`? Unless you insist on using implicit defaults (like the browser's default foreground color for text) you have to write it all out anyway.

Comment: Fragile because the inherited CSS from the parents is applied to the preview container, and if any amends are made to the parent stylesheet in the future the developer must also remember to make the corresponding overrides to the preview.

Comment: Secondly, when it comes to applying the styles to the preview you can either import the base stylesheet to the admin area which overrides all the admin styles – HTML5’s `<style scoped>` isn’t implemented yet, or you have to pull out just the styles needed then maintain them seperately in the admin stylesheet as being scoped to `#preview` (or whatever you’ve called it). An `<iframe>` isolates the CSS while leaving the content fully scriptable.